# PyQt5 - Program crashes when editable QGraphicsTextItem is clicked with right mouse button

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I've made a program with `PyQt5`. I have a main window containing a `QGraphicsScene` within a `QGraphicsView`. I have an editable `QGraphicsTextItem` in the scene as follows.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QApplication, QGraphicsTextItem

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsview = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.graphicsview)
        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget())
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.layout)
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.graphicsview.show()
        self.show()

        textitem = QGraphicsTextItem("Test")
        textitem.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.scene.addItem((textitem))



def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


main()
```

The problem is that the program crashes if the right mouse button is clicked within the textitem's area in the scene. The textitem and the text editor work fine as long as the right mouse button is not being clicked upon the item.

If I don't set the `TextEditorInteraction`, the right mouse button don't cause any problems.

I've tried using `setAcceptedMouseButtons()` -method to only allow left mouse button clicks on the item, but it has not had any effect. Not sure if I got the syntax right though.

I've tried to find a fix to this problem for quite a while now, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on linux using pyqt-5.15.4 with qt-5.15.2.

Comment: Please don't create new posts identical to existing one. You must give people time to answer. In any case, I cannot reproduce too on Linux. Are you using some particular interface (virtual keyboard, screen reader, etc.)? What system are you on and which PyQt version?

Comment: I'm using Win10 and PyCharm IDE. I have PyQt5 version 5.12.2.

Comment: @CalleRunqvist Test the script in a command window instead of the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on **PyQt** `5.15.2`, Win10 and **PyCharm IDE** *setup*. Running on command prompt does not produce any traceback error either. Event viewer gave some more details:

`"Faulting module name: Qt5Widgets.dll, version: 5.15.2.0, time stamp: 0x5fa4de1c Exception code: 0xc0000005"`.

It seems to be the code of a memory access issue but I couldnt find how it is anyway related to our problem here.

I had the following fix:

- Subclass a TextItem that handles the mouse press events.
- When right click change the editable text into non-editable mode.
- When left click change it back to editable mode.

```py
class TextItem(QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self,text):
        super().__init__(text)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextEditable)
            print("Left Button Clicked")
        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.NoTextInteraction)
            print("Right Button Clicked")
```